# cookieの署名方法はRFC化されていますか？

Tags: node.js, http, cookie

httpのcookieの署名の方法はRFC化されていますか？
ざっと調べたところ、そのようなRFCはありませんでした。

cookieの署名の方法はサーバー独自実装と考えても良いのでしょうか？

コメントをうけて補足します。

たとえば、node.jsでは「フィールド名.署名文字列」というドット区切りで署名文字列を書き込む機能があります。このフォーマットはnode.js独自の仕様なのか、RFCで決められた一般的な方法なのかということです。

Comment: Cookieについては、RFC 2109 (HTTP State Management Mechanism)がありますが、「署名方法」というのは、どのような事を指しているのでしょうか？